# Array Index Out of Bound using BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I am having a problem with `ArrayList` in java, so I tried to read input line by line using `BufferedReader` and the input stops until the user sends a blank line. Everything works fine until i try to read it line by line. 
I think I have handled it at that while() condition, but it returns `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`.

input example :

200 200

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
ArrayList<Villain> Villains = new ArrayList<Villain>();

String data;
while((data = reader.readLine()) != null)  
{
    data = reader.readLine();
    String[] Split = data.split(" ");
    int level = Integer.parseInt(Split[0]);
    int strength = Integer.parseInt(Split[1]);
    Villain vill = new Villain(level, strength);
    Villains.add(vill);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked length of `String[] Split = data.split(" ");`? Are you sure this split is happening, since you're trying to access element in next line?

Comment: You can check the length of the `Split` array to see if the user has entered a blank line, eg: `if(Split.length < 2){break;}`

Comment: is there any chance that i can avoid using break; ?

Comment: Since your reading from the console the `data` variable will never be `null` that is why you need to `break` from the loop.

Comment: ya, i found the problem, it was the splitter tried to split blank line, because it was no line so it returns ArrayIndexoutofBound

Comment: yes it works using break...
but i find something interesting here, when i use bufferedReader and i add 5 villains it only  3 of them recorded when i check the Villains.size();, but when i use Scanner all 5 were added to the Villains arrayList.
is there any explanation what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a single line.  So you would make the input "level strength".

Also by putting data = reader.readLine() in the while loop it makes the line after that not necessary.

This is what I have created using your code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
ArrayList<Villain> Villains = new ArrayList<Villain>();

String data;
while((data = reader.readLine()) != null)  
{
    String[] Split = data.split(" ");
    int level = Integer.parseInt(Split[0]);
    int strength = Integer.parseInt(Split[1]);
    System.out.println("Adding data.. level: " + level + ", strength: " + strength);
    Villain vill = new Villain(level, strength);
    Villains.add(vill);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are reading the user's input twice.
The user is going to enter only one line of text at a time no matter how long it is.
here:

```
String data;
// You read the user's input here and also check if it is not null
// Remember, it is not only checking if it's null but also reading input
while((data = reader.readLine()) != null)  
{
    // Then here again, you try reading the input again
    // Try commenting this line and see if it works.
    data = reader.readLine();
    String[] Split = data.split(" ");
    int level = Integer.parseInt(Split[0]);
    int strength = Integer.parseInt(Split[1]);
    Villain vill = new Villain(level, strength);
    Villains.add(vill);
}
```

Try it and lets know what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the second call to `readLine()`. It isn't a feature, it's a bug. You already have the next line, and you've already checked it for null. No point in just throwing it away and getting another unchecked one.